# Creating Blob in MYSQL using Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, servlets

Im  have a table in which one of the columns is to contain
a Blob.The content for the Blob is the content from a file
fromdisk.
    In order to write to the blob i need to have an output
stream to that blob.. but the mysql jdbc driver there is not
method
which out return me an output stream. (im using the hibernate with mysql)

How do i write my content in to theBlob ?
It seems the Oracle driver provides a
Blog.getBinaryOutputStream().... but what do I do im mysql

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated

Thanks,
Prabakar

Comment: It depends on which programming language you are going to use? Are you going for PHP ?

Comment: @Tan I would assume java due to Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the image as byte[] and you can persist the byte array.
See this link it might help
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-save-image-into-database/

Comment: see as well http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-save-get-blob-object-spring-3-mvc-hibernate/